# Using variable assigned in click()

Tags: jquery, click

How can I use a variable outside of a `click()` in `jQuery`? I have the following code -

```
$(".area").not(".enemy").click(function(){
                $(".area").removeClass("clicked");
                $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
                attackValue = $(this).text();           
        });
```

When I want to use attackValue outside of the `click()` It will not be defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to keep attackValue defined outside of the scope of the function, you will need to declare it outside of your click event.

```
var attackValue;

$(".area").not(".enemy").click(function(){ ... });
```

Now you should be able to reference it outside.

Comment: If OP declares the `attackValue` there without the `var` keyword. It is global and should be accessible outside the function. Although it is impossible to tell using that code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

For starters: this is NOT how you should declare a variable in javascript:

```
attackValue = $(this).text();
```

This would clutter 'programs' variable space. You should 'always' declare a variable in javascript using the `var` keyword.

> When I want to use attackValue outside of the click() It will not be defined.

It depends on where and when you want to use it. Consider the [following code](http://jsfiddle.net/PeeHaa/c7BHd/):

```
var attackValue = 'some value';

function setValue() {
  attackvalue = 'some other value';
}

console.log(attackvalue); // this would output some value, because the function hasn;t run yet
setValue();
```

However if you [would do](http://jsfiddle.net/PeeHaa/HGnWy/):

```
var attackValue = 'some value';

function setValue() {
  attackValue = 'some other value';
}

setValue();

console.log(attackValue); // this would output some other value, because the function did already run
```

Note that the above code should run in a [closure](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/). Or it would still clutter the variable space (even when using the `var`) keyword. So it would look more like:

```
(function() { // yay closure, now all variables defined in here will stay in here
    var attackValue = 'some value';

    function setValue() {
      attackValue = 'some other value';
    }

    setValue();    

    console.log(attackValue); // this would output some other value, because the function did already run
})();
```

​